# Can I make the latex extension .tex rather than .latex?

Tags: org-babel

When tangling latex source from `pie.org`, the resulting file is by default `pie.latex`.  Is it possible to change the extension for latex code to `.tex`?

Comment: Which version?  Section 12.7.1 of doc for 8.2.10 says " Export as a LaTeX file.  For an Org file ‘myfile.org’, the LaTeX file will be ‘myfile.tex’."

Comment: @JeanPierre, could that be inaccurate?  Either way, I'm using 9.0.2.

Comment: That is accurate for 8.2.10, just confirmed it on Emacs 25. It's still that way in org 9.0.1. Did you check with with emacs -Q?

Comment: @Tyler, just did.
 `#+BEGIN_SRC latex :tangle yes
 Test.
 #+END_SRC`
outputs `text.latex`.

Comment: I see. I was exporting, not tangling. Exporting generates a .tex file including all the org content, but tangling generates .latex files using only the contents of the source block. I mixed them up.

Comment: I made the same confusion, exporting vs tangling, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the variable `org-babel-tangle-lang-exts`, the documentation for which reads:

> Alist mapping languages to their file extensions.
>   The key is the language name, the value is the string that should
>   be inserted as the extension commonly used to identify files
>   written in this language.  **If no entry is found in this list,
>   then the name of the language is used.**

By default, there is no entry for latex. This is perhaps a buglet, but you can fix it for yourself by adding the appropriate values in the customize interface.

Comment: Thank you, Tyler! My variable only had entries for elisp from before ...

Comment: Yes, this seems like an oversight - it should probably include some sensible default values for other languages that don't use their own names as file extensions: latex, python, perl etc.